# how to store an Iterator value in a String in android

Tags: java, android, iterator

in my app when i click a button it hits an URL and gets back an xml file. From that xml file i am listing out a particular tag using dom parser and Iterator. Using the following code i am listing out the data's n the logcat.

```
Iterator<String> itr = arl.listIterator();
            int z=0,x=0,increment=0;
            while (itr.hasNext()) 
            {
                Log.e("ViewImage5-list all  "+z, itr.next());
                z++;
            }
```

Now the values which are all i am getting in logcat i want to store those values in an Array String. How to store it. Pls explain by code.....

Comment: Can you explain a bit more (preferably with code), how your parser and iterator work?

Comment: When you  iterate simply store all iteration values in temporary String variable. When your loop gets finished, you can store temporary String variable in your String constant..

Comment: If iterator having more than one value you have to store it in String Array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
Iterator<String> itr = arl.listIterator();
            int z=0,x=0,increment=0;
            List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (itr.hasNext()) 
            {
                String data = itr.next();
                list.add(data);
                Log.e("ViewImage5-list all  "+z, data);
                z++;
            }
            // the list "strings" now holds all your strings
```